# БД пользователей в Redis

Tags: php, авторизация, redis

Всем привет, как хранить данные регистрации пользователей в Redis?

База данных пользователей хранится в Redis.
Для каждого пользователя хранятся следующие поля:

1. Id
2. name
3. email
4. password_hash

Необходимо выполнить авторизацию пользователя по email и паролю (для комбинации email, password_hash получить данные пользователя).

функции на php:

```
/**
 * Creates new user
 *
 * @param array $user_data          User data contains the following fields:
 *                                      - name
 *                                      - email
 *                                      - password_hash
 *
 * @return string                   Returns ID of created user
 *
 * @throws \UserExistsException     Throws exception if user with this email already exists
 *
 */
function create_user(array $user_data)
{
    // your code here
}

/**
 * Finds user by combination of email and password hash
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @param string $password_hash
 *
 * @return string|null                   Returns ID of user or null if user not found
 */
function authorize_user($email, $password_hash)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Знаю как сделать форму и отправить данные в PHP функции, но совсем не понимаю как хранить данные в Redis

Comment: Найдите в сети мануал и следуйте ему.

Comment: Отличный совет.. Обратился сюда именно из-за того что не нашёл нужного мануала

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_php.htm

Comment: Это я уже читал, вопрос в том что я не знаю какие типы данных использовать для хранения логина и пароля пользователя, так же не получается записывать AUTO_INCREMENT для id. каждый раз id вручную указывать чтоли? В общем вопрос вот в чём, как правильно записывать такие данные как логин и пароль пользователя, а не как использовать redis для тривиальных задач...

Comment: настоятельно вам не рекомендую пользоваться in-memory хранилищами и тем более redis с его репутацией в качестве постоянного хранилища

Comment: На оф сайте есть туториал [клон твиттера](https://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone), там как раз регистрация пользователей и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку

Comment: ID юзера не обязательно должен быть числовым. Можно использовать UUID (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). Для PHP есть либа https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Answer (score 1):

Для подобного кейса подойдет хранить данные пользователя в хэш таблице редиса.
https://redis.io/commands/hmset

А в качестве ключа для удобства можно использовать пару email + password_hash в md5. Таким образом доступ будет по прямому ключу, проверка с помощью exists и.т.д. Будет работать быстро и без оверхеда.
Доставать данные через hgetall или hmget (в зависимости от того что нужно все поля или некоторые).

```
$key = md5($email, $passwordHash);
$allFields = $redis->hgetall($key);
$someFields = $redis->hmget($key, 'id', 'name');
```

Реализация может отличатся в зависимости от клиента для редиса. Лично я рекомендую юзать predis (https://github.com/nrk/predis)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->connect('localhost', 6379); # Подключаемся
    $redis->select(1); # Выбираем БД №1
} catch(RedisException $e) {
    exit('Connect error');
}
```

Запись:

```
$redis->set(intval($redis->get('lastid')), json_encode(array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'password_hash' => $password_hash
)));
$redis->incr('lastid');
```

Последний добавленный юзер:

```
print_r(json_decode($redis->get($redis->get('lastid')),true));
```

Список команд: https://redis.io/commands

Comment: Спасибо, это уже больше похоже на правду)